# PHP utf encoding problem

Tags: php, encoding, utf-16, utf

How can I encode strings on UTF-16BE format in PHP? For "Demo Message!!!" the encoded string should be '00440065006D006F0020004D00650073007300610067006'. Also, I need to encode Arabic characters to this format.

Comment: Sorry, this ain't UTF-8 as you may have already noticed. it seems to be UTF-16BE.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, this is absolutly not UTF-8, which is just a charset *(i.e. a way to store strings in memory / display them)*.

WHat you have here looks like a dump of the bytes that are used to build each characters.

If so, you could get those bytes this way :

```
$str = utf8_encode("Demo Message!!!");

for ($i=0 ; $i<strlen($str) ; $i++) {
    $byte = $str[$i];
    $char = ord($byte);
    printf('%02x ', $char);
}
```

And you'd get the following output :

```
44 65 6d 6f 20 4d 65 73 73 61 67 65 21 21 21
```

But, once again, this is not UTF-8 : in UTF-8, like you can see in the example I've give, `D` is stored on only one byte : `0x44`

In what you posted, it's stored using two Bytes : `0x00 0x44`.

Maybe you're using some kind of UTF-16 ?

---

**EDIT after a bit more testing and @aSeptik's comment :** this is indeed UTF-16.

To get the kind of dump you're getting, you'll have to make sure your string is encoded in UTF-16, which could be done this way, using, for example, the [**`mb_convert_encoding`**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-convert-encoding.php) function :

```
$str = mb_convert_encoding("Demo Message!!!", 'UTF-16', 'UTF-8');
```

Then, it's just a matter of iterating over the bytes that make this string, and dumping their values, like I did before :

```
for ($i=0 ; $i<strlen($str) ; $i++) {
    $byte = $str[$i];
    $char = ord($byte);
    printf('%02x ', $char);
}
```

And you'll get the following output :

```
00 44 00 65 00 6d 00 6f 00 20 00 4d 00 65 00 73 00 73 00 61 00 67 00 65 00 21 00 21 00 21
```

Which kind of looks like what youy posted :-)

*(you just have to remove the space in the call to `printf` -- I let it there to get an easier to read output=)*

Comment: @aSeptik : Thanks :-) ;; I've edited my answer to add some informations about that :-)

Comment: he can also check with `mb_detect_encoding('00440065006D006F0020004D00650073007300610067006');` -> ASCII

Comment: @Pascal Martin: I'd got the dump by using printf("%04x", $char); instead of printf("%02x ", $char); in your first answer. Now I'm confused. What's the difference?

Comment: With %04x, you'll be displaying 4 digits per byte ;;; with %02x, you'll be displaying 2 digits per byte ;;; after that, it's a matter of encoding : with UTF-8, which is what is used in my first portion of code, some characters are stored on one byte, some other are stored on two bytes, some on 3, and, if I remember correctly, some on 4 bytes

Comment: all the characters used in your example strings are "simple" characters, stored on 1 byte when using UTF-8, which explains why the first portion of code doesn't output any `00`. ;;; but with more complex characters, you'll see that you need to iterate byte by byte, and use %02d, to display the value of each byte.

Comment: @Pascal Martin: I need one more help.. Instead of printing the encoded string, I want to take the whole string to a variable... How can I do it?

Comment: @shyam : you can use the `sprintf` function *( http://fr2.php.net/sprintf )*, instead of `printf` : it will return the result, instead of printing it ;; just concatenate the result each time `sprintf` is called : `$string .= sprintf('...', ...)`

Answer (score 0):

E.g. by using the [mbstring](http://docs.php.net/mbstring) extension and its [mb_convert_encoding()](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-convert-encoding.php) function.

```
$in = 'Demo Message!!!';
$out = mb_convert_encoding($in, 'UTF-16BE');

for($i=0; $i<strlen($out); $i++) {
  printf("%02X ", ord($out[$i]));
}
```

prints

```
00 44 00 65 00 6D 00 6F 00 20 00 4D 00 65 00 73 00 73 00 61 00 67 00 65 00 21 00 21 00 21
```

Or by using [iconv()](http://docs.php.net/iconv)

```
$in = 'Demo Message!!!';
$out = iconv('iso-8859-1', 'UTF-16BE', $in);

for($i=0; $i<strlen($out); $i++) {
  printf("%02X ", ord($out[$i]));
}
```